# Can I update the Authors AFTER I've done a git-svn clone?

Tags: svn, git

I've seen tutorials that talk about creating a .gitusers file and converting your SVN authors to git users while doing a repo clone (via using the svn.authorsfile config option). However, our SVN repo takes 6-8 hours to clone and I don't want to do that again.

Is there any way to retroactively update my git repo to use the correct git authors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the only way would be using filter-branch, but that would result in a different, parallel tree than the one used by git-svn, so every git svn fetch/rebase would have to be cherry picked / rebased on top of this "new tree".

Comment: Gotcha. Far from desirable, but it answers my question :)